# mysql/php Ignore set if value is null

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyway to ignore the set CalDate and DueDate if they are null and still succeed to update the values that are entered and **save the old** value on **CalDate** and **DueDate**?

```
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status', CalDate='$CalDate', DueDate='$DueDate' WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')";
}
```

This code set a value of 0000-00-00 if null which is understandable but I do like it to ignore that in that case.

Comment: Inside your db those field can be null?

Comment: $upd is a string. If $CalDate is null do not add that code to the query. So build your query dynamically ;)

Comment: Aha ok I will try to build up an if/else statement. Thought there was a similar way to isset but it may not be?

Comment: You can use the isset to check, but you need an if(isset($var)) . At least i think this way

Comment: Yeah but thanks anyway I was about to do it the way @Sarath posted, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
  if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){

        $upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status'";
        if($CalDate !='')
           $upd.= ",CalDate='$CalDate'";
        if($DueDate !='') 
           $upd .= ",DueDate='$DueDate'";
        $upd .=" WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){
    $set = "status = '$status'";
    if ( ! empty($CalDate) ) $set .= ", CalDate = '$CalDate'";
    if ( ! empty($DueDate) ) $set .= ", DueDate = '$DueDate'";
    $upd = "UPDATE booking 
        SET $set 
        WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){
    $query = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status'";
    if($CalDate != NULL ){
        $query .= ", CalDate='$CalDate'";
        //Run this query to get the CalDate
        //"SELECT CalDate FROM booking WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')"
        //Get the result into $CalDate
    }
    if($DueDate != NULL ){
        $query .= ", DueDate='$DueDate'";
        //Run this query to get the DueDate
        //"SELECT DueDate FROM booking WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')"
        //Get the result into $DueDate
    }
    $query .= " WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')";

    $upd = $query;
}
```